# Altium schematic annotation

Tags: altium

I would like to ask how I can create annotation for two similar pages constinusly? Right now I have R7_1 and R7_2 and so on. But I want create from R6 to R14 and next start with R15. Added pictures for example.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can fix this, go to Tools/ Annotation / Annotate Schematic.

Then you can fix the start index for each schematic sheet.

[image]

Comment: This don't solve my problem. Annotation is the same but with different designers.